# Java ME & LWUIT on Blackberry and Android

Tags: android, blackberry, java-me, lwuit

Is it possible to write a platform independent application in Java ME & LWUIT?

More specifically, can I write apps which run on both Android and Blackberry?

Comment: Take a look at J2ME Polish and/or CodenameOne. Google them. Not 100% what you're after, but pretty close.

Comment: Hi mr_lou, J2ME Polish is having really good features but also it has lot of bugs which are need to be addressed so J2ME Polish is not good alternative for LWUIT

Comment: Closing this question is entirely too hasty. There is a specific programming question to answer - can LWUIT be used to build an app that runs on both BlackBerry and Android, and there is a nice answer.  This is a real question.

Comment: In short the answer is Yes, but for the future i support silwar's answer. If you absolutely must then it is possible with some headaches, the outcome is not great either. Codenameone is an upgrade to LWUIT which should give less hassles porting across platforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer is NO. LWUIT is great for J2ME development as it enables SWING kind of development approach in J2ME but for Android and BlackBerry LWUIT is not that much useful.
There are two reasons

1. Android is ever evolving technology where you will get latest Views and different options to enhance your application functionality. So using LWUIT for Android is not good choice
2. You can also develop BlackBerry application using LWUIT but again I would suggest to use native BB development as it provides stack of screens and many other options which are not present in LWUIT

Apart from this latest versions of BlackBerry also facilitates Android code to run on BB devices so better to go for Android development and BB development if needed

To answer your last question which is **Is Java ME & LWUIT technology worth exploring?** again answer is **NO**.

Reason for this is J2ME was developed for devices with lower configuration and with less in memory which is not the scenario for current mobile devices. and also J2ME is developed with reducing size of Java where Android has developed by enhancing Java in its own way so better go with technology which is extensible enough for the future

Answer (score 0):

> Specifically, will I be able to write apps for Android and Blackberry using Java ME and LWUIT?

I cannot speak for Blackberry. Android does not use Java ME, and I am not aware of any Android devices that have separately licensed Java ME for running such apps. I have heard rumors of compatibility libraries to help Java ME apps be ported to Android, but I have no experience with such libraries.

With respect to LWUIT, while it may be possible to create Android applications using this, it does not appear to be especially popular.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, its correct that Android does not use Java ME but LWUIT provides support to blackberry as well android. Please check [this](http://lwuit.java.net/)